# Variance of Quadratic form

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution, quadratic-form

From the Wikipedia

> In general, the variance of a quadratic form depends greatly on the
>   distribution of ${\displaystyle \varepsilon }$ . However, if
>   ${\displaystyle \varepsilon }$ does follow a multivariate normal
>   distribution, the variance of the quadratic form becomes particularly
>   tractable. Assume for the moment that $A$  is a symmetric matrix.
>   Then, if $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$
>
> $$Var( \varepsilon^t A \varepsilon ) = 2\text{trace}(A \Sigma A \Sigma) + 4\mu^t A \Sigma A \mu $$

I was wondering if there are other distributions where this or some similar  property hold. Looking at the proof for the gaussian case the moment generating function of $\varepsilon^tA \varepsilon$ is used so  I do not find an easy way to generalize.

I am willing to consider the case where the property hold for any poisitive definite matrix $A$ and with $\mu =\vec 0$.

Comment: What makes such a formula possible isn't the Gaussian form; rather, all Gaussian distributions have the same kurtosis.

Comment: @whuber I am sorry but I do not follow what you are saying.

Comment: Go through the "proof for the Gaussian case" you allude to and watch for the point where the kurtosis enters.

Comment: @whuber I came across this comment and am also confused by it. The book cited in the Wikipedia article says, when proving the variance formula: "... normality
is assumed in obtaining the moment generating function of y'Ay and var(y'Ay) in the
following theorems.", as pointed out by the question.

Comment: @dherrera The distribution of $y$ determines its mgf and it also determines the distribution of $x = y^\prime A y.$  The present question does not concern the distribution: it asks only about the variance of $x.$  That is determined only by the first four moments of $y.$